# Efficiency of sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Can I make this more efficient?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void setvalue(int array_copy[], int i, int n)
{
    int j,p;

    for(j = i*i ; j <= n ; j +=(i*2) )
    {
        array_copy[j] = 1;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int n,i,l=0,sq;
    scanf("%i",&n);

    sq = sqrt(n);



    int prime_array[n];
    int array[n];
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    for ( i = 4; i <= n; i+=2)
    {
        array[i] = 1;
    }

    for( i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)
    {
        setvalue(array,i,n);
    }
    array[2] = 0;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == 0)
        {
            prime_array[l] = i;
            l++;
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i <= (l-1) ; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",prime_array[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer : most of my comments might be irrelevant as far as performance is concerned but should make your code better on different other aspects (readability for instance).*

**Listen to your compiler**

Compiling your code with `gcc -Wall your_file -lm` gives me the following warning : `sieve.c:7:11: warning: unused variable ‘p’ [-Wunused-variable]`. I guess you know the first thing you can do :-).

**Making things easier to follow**

Splitting your code in small chunks is usually a good idea. Unfortunately, I am not quite convinced by `setvalue` because what it does is quite complicated and it makes it hard to give it a simple name, to test it out of the algorithm or to reuse it later on. Thus, from my point of view, it's easier to just remove this function.

**A good habit : defining things in the smallest possible scope**

It is quite common to try to define variables as late as possible and in the smallest possible scope. It prevents whoever reads the code to try to keep in mind the value of irrelevant things and to find what is used for what and it allows one to find easily when a variable becomes unused.

It makes even better if you use `c99` as you can them define indices in for-loops.

Also, you can take this chance to define things that go together (such as `prime_array` and `l`) together.

**Consistency**

You should try to be consistent in how you write your code. You should define a way to put space in your code and try to stick to it as much as possible. Consistency is relevant also for braces (you did good), line breaks, incrementations (you used `i++` and `++i`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 100; //scanf("%i",&n);

    int sq = sqrt(n);

    int array[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 4; i <= n; i+=2)
    {
        array[i] = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)
    {
        for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j+=(i*2))
        {
            array[j] = 1;
        }
    }
    array[2] = 0;

    int prime_array[n];
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            prime_array[l] = i;
            l++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= (l-1) ; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",prime_array[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Keeping things simple**

If you just want to write prime number on the standard output, you don't really need a temporary container for the numbers.

**Naming things**

> There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache
>   invalidation and naming things. -- Phil Karlton

Naming is really important : here `array` is a pretty bad name as it doesn't convey any information about how the array is used.

Because of the way you use it, naming it `not_prime` would probably be a good idea. An even better idea would be to name it `prime` (or something like that) and use it in such a way that a true-ish value corresponds to prime number and 0 to non-prime numbers. Then you'd get something like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 100; //scanf("%i",&n);

    int sq = sqrt(n);

    int prime[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        prime[i] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 4; i <= n; i+=2)
    {
        prime[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)
    {
        for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j+=(i*2))
        {
            prime[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    prime[2] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i])
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Algorithm**

This is probably where it gets interesting : you have not properly implemented the sieve. At the moment, you apply the logic (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_description)) `Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in increments of p, and mark them in the list (these will be 2p, 3p, 4p, etc.; the p itself should not be marked).` for `p` being the `i` in `for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)` but you should (or you can depending on the point of view) restrict yourself to prime values of `i`. This corresponds to adding `if (prime[i])`.  This should have a huge impact from a performance point of view.

**A tiny problem**

There is a variation of the quote above that goes like this :

> There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache
>   invalidation, off-by-one errors and naming things.

It is relevant in your case because you have an array of `n` elements so the last index you should access is `n - 1`. The usual way to write the corresponding loop is with `i < n` (instead of the equivalent `i <= n-1`).

The `i <= sq` stays the same, I'll let you understand why on your own.

The code is now :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 122; //scanf("%i",&n);

    int sq = sqrt(n);

    int prime[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        prime[i] = 1;
    }
    prime[2] = 1;
    for (int i = 4; i < n; i+=2)
    {
        prime[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)
    {
        if (prime[i])
        {
            for (int j = i*i; j < n; j+=(i*2))
            {
                prime[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i])
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Comments**

Even though you have missed an key step in the algorithm, you have tried some fancy optimisation, it would probably be worth commenting on those to explain why and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give you the biggest improvement:

```
for( i = 3; i <= sq; i+=2)
{
    // You only have to do the sieve for primes.
    // So check array[i] to see if this is a prime.
    if (array[i] == 0)
        setvalue(array,i,n);
}
```

Also, your `array` is too small by one.  If you use `i <= n` and `j <= n` everywhere, then `array` needs to be of size `n+1`.

You also don't need a separate `prime_array`.  You can compact your `array` without using a copy:

```
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 0)
        array[l++] = i;
}
```